# 40lb.round of opened grana padano cheese

Tags: cheese

I bought a 80lb. round of Grano Padano cheese and had it opened horizontally to use 1/2 of it for wedding. We "chunked" out a good portion of the center so the guests could nibble on it while tasting wine. The other 1/2 we would like to save for another wedding that is 3 months away. We want to keep it uncut and do the same thing for the  Pre-dinner wine tasting. My question is: What is the best way to preserve it? I might be able to cryovac the whole piece and freeze it, but I understand it might lose some flavor and become crumbly. I can also refrigerate it. Would wrapping it in wax paper, then heavy duty aluminum foil, be the best way? I would be grateful for any answers!

Answer (score 7):

[image: yellow/clear cheese wax]

I think your best bet might be to re-wax the cut surface with [cheese wax](http://www.cheesemaking.com/shop/cheese-wax-yellow.html), available from cheesemaking suppliers, and then store in the fridge, unless you have a cheese cave handy. In general a vertical halving will reduce storage loss by minimizing the cut surface - you could have had the same cheese availability by vertically halving the wheel (with a smaller cut surface) and then horizontally slicing the half you were using, opening it like a book if looking for the "whole round of cheese" look.

Your other best bet might be a bit too late, which is to be sure wedding one has paid for the whole cheese, and wedding two is prepared to pay for a whole cheese, so that if you open it up in 3 months and have a problem, the problem is only "smaller profit" not "taking a loss on trying to store cheese for 90 days after opening."

*Linked item is just one I found as an example, not affiliated or even a customer.*

Answer (score 1):

Freezing the cheese is OK.

Grana Padano is a hard cheese (it does not slice easily and does not spread); and will mostly be used shredded or grated; so texture loss due to freezing will not be an issue.

As in all frozen things, freeze as fast as possible (make small portions, if possible to speed up the freezing process) and thaw as slowly as possible (in the fridge over a couple of days).

In the case of a large chunk like yours, you might have to scrape a little bit of the outside surface when the cheese it thawed (moisture accumulation will be the surface a little bit gooey.